# kaazing websocket with gae

Tags: java, google-app-engine, xmpp, websocket

any demo on using kaazing websocket with gae?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Websockets are not currently supported on App Engine. Browser Push is on [the roadmap](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/roadmap.html), however.